# Backbone.Marionette not recognising Marionette function

Tags: node.js, express, backbone.js, pug, marionette

I have the following jade template, containing the link to Marionette (on a CDN) and all the dependencies, which I've checked and are listed in the correct order. However, the following code:

```
extends layout

block content
  h2 Characters and Portraits
  div(class="container") Portraits Loading...
  script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-cRpWjoSOw5KcyIOaZNo4i6fZ9tKPhYYb6i5T9RSVJG8=" crossorigin="anonymous")
  script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.min.js")
  script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js")
  script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js")
  script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/3.0.0/backbone.marionette.min.js")
  script.
    var CharacterTemplating = new Marionette.Application();
    CharacterTemplating.on("start", function(){
    console.log("Character Templating has started!");
    });
    CharacterTemplating.start();
```

Results in this error:

```
characters:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: Marionette is not defined
```

The code is serving from a node/express server process. Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Update: I checked in the network traffic and it doesn't look like the Marionette library is being loaded in for some reason. Checking to see if loading it in from elsewhere helps...

Update: Loading the dependency in from another CDN does cause the Backbone.Marionette library to appear in the network traffic, but now I'm getting this error instead:

```
backbone.marionette.min.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined(anonymous function) @ backbone.marionette.min.js:19(anonymous function) @ backbone.marionette.min.js:14(anonymous function) @ backbone.marionette.min.js:14
characters:5 Uncaught TypeError: Marionette.Application is not a constructor
```

The code is barely changed from the sample code in the book I'm using for reference (Backbone.Marionette: A Gentle Introduction) so it should work... Looking to see if there might be another basic reference to use as a guide. Perhaps a more up-to-date one...

Update: tried again using the syntax in the main Backbone.Marionette API documentation:

```
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette');
```

followed by:

```
var CharacterTemplating = new Mn.Application();
```

which resulted in this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

So it looks like node isn't available from within the Jade template; hhhhmmmm... Not sure I should even be needing to require marionette in with node anyway, since I'm including it in the scripts.

Comment: that `require` is probably commonjs on the front-end, not on the server-side.